# Why is my garbage collection time spiking in HBASE Region Server?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, hbase, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I have a Cloudera HBASE Server that showing a spike in GC Time (20s) which causes my Spark Streaming Executor tasks to fail because the Phoenix queries are taking longer than the timeout limit (60s).

I'm not an expert on GC, and I'm way over my head to figure out the GC tuning parameters. But is there a reason why the GC time is spiking up on HBASE Region server? Or is there a specific parameter I need to apply to get GC to run at interval instead of it triggering when the heap is filled?

My Spark Streaming Application runs 24/7 and its been fine in production for years until now.

Here's the graph of the GC time, cpu usage, and memory usage.
[image]

HBASE Region Server is running on Centos with Java 1.7_67; it's managed by Cloudera CDH 5.10.
Three Region Servers running on AWS m5.xlarge (4 vCPU, 16GB Ram).

Here's the Java options thats running the HBASE RegionServer:

```
-Xms2147483648 -Xmx2147483648 -XX:+UseParNewGC 
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled 
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
-XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp/hbase_hbase-REGIONSERVER-a79693382d05d90e92d12135c6a45fc1_pid{{PID}}.hprof
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError={{AGENT_COMMON_DIR}}/killparent.sh
```

Comment: It is hard to tell, but it looks like the GC is running more frequently than it should.  A common cause for that is that the heap is too close to being full and that is triggering a lot of GC runs and ... maybe ... triggering CMS to do too many fallback collections because the normal strategies are failing to keep up.

Comment: 1) Look at the GC logs.  2) Use a profiler and analyse your code look for possible memory leaks. 3) Consider upgrading to (at least) Java 11 so that you can make use of more modern Java garbage collectors.

Comment: I added options to log the GC and restarted HBASE but it'll take some time for HBASE to start triggering the massive GC.
I don't have access to HBASE code, nor is my application running on the HBASE host, so there's nothing I can do code wise. Also I don't think I can upgrade the Java version because Cloudera CDH 5.10 only supports 1.7 and 1.8.

Comment: Java 8 would be an improvement.

Comment: Hard stuff  GC for sure

Comment: Does this apply? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596717/hbase-memstore-and-garbage-collection
Also this https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Tuning-Hbase-for-optimized-performance-Part-3/ta-p/248159 might be useful (see JVM metrics section towards the end).

Comment: Did you try increasing the heap size?

Comment: @shay__ I increased the heap size from 2G to 4G but the problem still occurs. I also changed the GC algorithm to g1gc and STW pauses are under 100ms and under 5.353 secs per minute.


I'm still trying to figure out why my HBASE is taking too long (over 60s) to query SELECT several rows from a DB with 4 primary keys. It's usually very quick in few to several seconds.

Comment: Reducing hbase.hregion.max.filesize from 10GB to 5GB helped significantly reduce my query time by breaking regions of 6-8GB to 4GB.

My region servers are healthier and does not trigger full GC and significantly reduces my Phoenix query time to under 60s.